# QApplication - Cannot use of IWbemLocator in Qt

Tags: qt, winapi, wmi

I want to write a `WMI` application using windows API and COM library in `Qt`.

I include `<qt_windows.h>` to access windows `API` , I tried this before in *Visual Studio*.

But when I include `Wbemidl.h` to declare a `IWbemLocator` variable, the compiler give me the following `error` :

> ```
> error: Wbemidl.h: No such file or directory
> ```

This is a section of my `code` :

```
HRESULT hResult = S_OK;                 // Result of initializing com library
BOOL    bIsComLibUninit = FALSE;        // A flag that determine if com library is loaded

// Initialize COM library
hResult = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
// If a previous call of CoInitializeEx occured in this thread
if(hResult == RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE)
{
    OleUninitialize();
    bIsComLibUninit = TRUE;
}
else if(hResult == S_OK)
{
    bIsComLibUninit = TRUE;
}

// If COM library uninitialized
if(bIsComLibUninit == TRUE)
{
    // Initialize COM library
    hResult = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if(hResult == S_OK)
    {
        // Initialize security
        hResult = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL,
                                       RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
                                       RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
                                       NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL);
        if(hResult == S_OK)
        {
            IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;
            CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                             IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);
            // Do stuffs
        }
    }

    // Uninitialize COM library
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error message tells that compiler can't find the header file.

1. Try to find the "Wbemidl.h" in your location(e.g. the Path in my local: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\um`), and add the PATH to your compiler. Also don't forget the .lib reference.
2. If you can't find this header file, try to download sdk from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/further-information), select one which suits you: